# C++ static variables of unreferenced class

Tags: c++, templates, static

In the following program "Here" is printed:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
  static bool temp;
  static bool initTemp()
  {std::cout<<"Here\n";return true;}
};

bool Base::temp = Base::initTemp();

class Derived : public Base
{};

int main() {int a;std::cin>>a;}
```

In the following program "Here" is not printed:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class Base
{
  static bool temp;
  static bool initTemp()
  {std::cout<<"Here\n";return true;}
};

template <class T>
bool Base<T>::temp = Base<T>::initTemp();

class Derived : public Base<int>
{};

int main() {int a;std::cin>>a;}
```

In both cases Base is never referenced. The only difference is that in the second case it is a template class. Can anyone explain to me why this behavior occurs. I am using VS 2012.

Comment: `void main()` is not legal C++.  Should be `int main()`.

Comment: In the second example, "Here" is printed if you explicitly instantiate the static member: `template bool Base<int>::temp;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In both cases Base is never referenced.

And that is precisely the reason why you see nothing being printed to the standard output.

The definition of a class template's static data member does not get instantiated unless you use that data member; like member functions, the definitions of static data members of a class template are instantiated *on demand*.

This is specified in paragraph 14.7.1/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions,
>   member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members** and member templates. [...]

Since your client code never refers to `Base<>::temp`, there is no need to construct and initialize it.

---

As a side note, this signature:

```
void main()
```

Is not valid (standard) C++. If you want to write portable code, the return type of `main()` should always be `int`.

Comment: But the code contains `class Derived : Base<int>` … (why) doesn’t that count as instantiation?

Comment: I edited the post so that it uses int. Is there any way to instantiate the class by inheriting from it? i.e. is there any way to automatically initialize temp for many different derived types without having to write                                template<>bool Base<int>::temp=Base<int>::initTemp();

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "*The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions,
member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates*" (14.7.1/1)

Comment: @BenjyKessler: OK, I will edit the answer to reflect your edit

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you don't instantiate `Base`, but you do call the static function:

```
bool Base::temp = Base::initTemp();
```

In the second case, you never instantiate the `template`:

```
template <class T>
bool Base<T>::temp = Base<T>::initTemp();
```

You can explicitly instantiate the `Base` class template, as with:

```
template class Base<int>;
```

And then you will see "Here" printed.

Comment: OK that's cool, I didn't know that forward declaring a template class instantiates it.

Comment: @BenjyKessler: That's not a forward declaration, it's an explicit instantiation

Comment: @BenjyKessler: lol, yes, edited the comment. My brain is sleeping

Answer (score -3):

You cannot create variable of undefined class, which you seem to do with line:

```
template <class T>
bool Base<T>::temp = Base<T>::initTemp();
```

You cannot allocate variable of undefined type. What you need is write something like:

```
Base<int>::temp = value;
```

of cause there will be different variable allocated for each type provided, so you cannot have common static variable for a template class. You'll have separate variable for each type you instantiate your template instead.

To downvoters here is complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class X
{
public:
    static int v;
};

template<class T>
int X<T>::v = 0;

int main()
{
    X<int>::v = 3;
    X<char>::v = 2;

    using namespace std;
    cout << X<char>::v << endl << X<int>::v;
}
```

It prints 2 3 which means you cannot have single variable for all classes you'll instantiate your template.

Comment: I think what Bogolt meant is that for every different instanstiation of X you will have a different value of v. That is true but I want to have a different value of v for every instantiation. In order to share the same static variable among all instantiations X should inherit from some non-template base class which contains v.

Comment: Your code example actually shows that you *can* do exactly what you claim you cannot do.

Comment: I claim that when you use variable of a template class it depends on a type template was instantiated. And that by creating single variable you actually create a number of variables for each class instantiation. Do not really see when i was saying the opposite.

Comment: Well you claim that “What you need is write something like: `Base<int>::temp = value;`” and that is patently untrue. The rest is just distraction.